# How to return a float with 'text/csv' as "Content-Type" from SageMaker endpoint that uses custom inference code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to return output(or predictions) from a SageMaker endpoint with 'text/csv' or 'text/csv; charset=utf-8' as "Content-Type". I have tried multiple ways, but the sagemaker always returns with 'text/html; charset=utf-8' as the "Content-Type", and I would like SageMaker to return 'text/csv' or 'text/csv; charset=utf-8'.

Here's the [`output_fn`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/sklearn/using_sklearn.html#process-output) from my inference-code:

```
** my other code **
def output_fn(prediction, content_type='text/csv'):
    ** my other code **
    return output_float
```

above function returns number with float data-type and I got error(in cloudwatch logs) that  this function should only be returning string, tuple, dict or Respoonse instance.

So, here are all the different ways I have tried to have SageMaker return my number with 'text/csv' but only receives 'text/html; charset=utf-8'

1. `return json.dumps(output_float)`. this sent 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.
2. `return f"{output_float}"`. this sent 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.
3. `return f"{output_float},"`. this sent 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.
4. `return f"{output_float}\n"`. this sent 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.
5. `return f"{output_float},\n"`. this sent 'text/html; charset=utf-8'.
6. by using [`sagemaker.serializers.CSVSerializer`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/serializers.html) like this:

   ```
   from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
   csv_serialiser = CSVSerializer(content_type='text/csv')

   def output_fn(prediction, content_type='text/csv'):
       ** my other code **
       return csv_serialiser.serialize(output_float)
   ```

   I got `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'` error with this.
7. as a tuple: `return (output_float,)`. I haven't noted down what this did, but it sure didn't return the number with 'text/csv' as "Content-Type".
8. made changes in my model object to return a float on calling `.predict_proba` on my model-object and deployed it from sagemaker studio without using any custom inference code and deployed this from SageMaker studio. but got this error after sending a request to the endpoint: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'`, but at my side, when I pass proper inputs to the unpicked model and call .predict_proba, i get float as expected.
9. by returning [`flask.Response`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/flask.Response.html#flask.Response) like this:

   ```
   from flask import Response

   def output_fn(prediction, content_type='text/csv'):
       ** my other code **
       return Response(response=output_float, status=200, headers={'Content-Type':'text/csv; charset=utf-8'})
   ```

   but, I got some IndexError with this(I didn't notedown the traceback.)

Some other info:

1. Model I am using is completely outside of SageMaker, not from a training job or anything like that.
2. All of the aforementioned endpoints have been deployed entirely from aws-cli with relevant .json files, except the one in point-8 above.

How do I return number with "text/csv" as content-type from sagemaker? I need my output in "text/csv" content-type specifically for Model-Quality-Monitor. How do I do this?

Comment: I wonder if something might be setting an `Accept` header on the request to HTML... How are you invoking your endpoint? `predictor.predict()`? `boto3`? If using SM Python SDK `predictor`, what's your `deserializer`?

Comment: i have been tesitng this from Postman and python-requests. my "Accept" parameter has been "*/*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [scikit_bring_your_own](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/container/decision_trees/predictor.py#L88) example, I suggest testing by setting the Response as follows:

```
return flask.Response(response= output_float, status=200, mimetype="text/csv")
```

Comment: for anyone reading this answer in the future, according to my question, `output_float` was a float or number, but `response` of `flask.Response` only accepts hashable inputs and in this case, number should be converted to str.